# Webpack images folder

Tags: webpack

I am fairly new to webpack.

When I deploy I basically get a **JS** file and a bunch of images which have been garbled up like this in the same folder :

[image]

I would like for this ***not*** to happen.

I want to have the image files maintain their names, because in my javascript I would like to dynamically load the image files and whatever else I have in my resources file.

I would like them to be in their own folder where I can access them.

My webpack file looks like this :

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,

  entry: "./js/client.js",

  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css|\.less$/, loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"] },
      { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.PNG$|\.svg$|\.woff(2)?$|\.ttf$|\.eot$/,
        loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  },

  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior for the file-loader is to name each file as "[hash].[ext]" as [documented here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#options). If you would like to keep the same filename, you'll need to override the name option to be "[name].[ext]". If you'd like to keep the original path structure as well, you can use the "[path]" in that expression as well.

In this case you could try:

```
{
  test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.PNG$|\.svg$|\.woff(2)?$|\.ttf$|\.eot$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[name].[ext]'
  }  
}
```

There are other documented options on the page referenced above as well.

Comment: thanks that works, but it doesn't solve the problem of me having an arbitrary large number of image files, and me wanting to retrieve one of those files. Webpack only knows about the files when there is for example an 'import' of that file. If I have 200 image files in the folder, i want webpack to dump all those 200 files on the server without me needing to import each one.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not valid for Webpack 5. Here's the [updated documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#custom-output-filename) for creating a custom output filename :

By default, `asset/resource modules` are emitting with `[hash][ext][query]` filename into output directory.

You can modify this template by setting `output.assetModuleFilename` in your webpack configuration:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
+   assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.png/,
        type: 'asset/resource'
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

Another case to customize output filename is to emit some kind of assets to a specified directory:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.png/,
        type: 'asset/resource'
-     }
+     },
+     {
+       test: /\.html/,
+       type: 'asset/resource',
+       generator: {
+         filename: 'static/[hash][ext][query]'
+       }
     }
    ]
  },
};
```

With this configuration all the `html` files will be emitted into a `static` directory within the output directory.

`Rule.generator.filename` is the same as `output.assetModuleFilename` and works only with `asset` and `asset/resource` module types.

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore them (use the [IgnorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/)) and use the [CopyWebpackPlugin](http://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to copy the files to their destination directory. Perhaps that will suffice to "dump" them on the server.