# Webpack: Favicon in public folder not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, public-html

I'm using React + Webpack. I'm currently trying to install a favicon but it's not working.

I have this in my public/index.html file:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-57x57.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-60x60.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-72x72.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-76x76.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-114x114.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-120x120.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-144x144.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-152x152.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-180x180.png"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/android-icon-192x192.png"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/favicon-32x32.png"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/favicon-96x96.png"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/favicon-16x16.png"/>
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/manifest.json">
```

And this is my public folder:

```
public
├── icons
│   ├── android-icon-144x144.png
│   ├── android-icon-192x192.png
│   ├── android-icon-36x36.png
│   ├── android-icon-48x48.png
│   ├── android-icon-72x72.png
│   ├── android-icon-96x96.png
│   ├── apple-icon-114x114.png
│   ├── apple-icon-120x120.png
│   ├── apple-icon-144x144.png
│   ├── apple-icon-152x152.png
│   ├── apple-icon-180x180.png
│   ├── apple-icon-57x57.png
│   ├── apple-icon-60x60.png
│   ├── apple-icon-72x72.png
│   ├── apple-icon-76x76.png
│   ├── apple-icon-precomposed.png
│   ├── apple-icon.png
│   ├── browserconfig.xml
│   ├── favicon-16x16.png
│   ├── favicon-32x32.png
│   ├── favicon-96x96.png
│   ├── favicon.ico
```

However, when I load the page it tells me that those icons don't exist.

[image]

Which part of the webpack config allows me to open access to the public folder?

Comment: A hope this working for you, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456598/webpack-images-folder)